# Why in $Q$-Learning, policy $\pi$ is evaluated through another policy $u$?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I've been watching David Silver's [courses](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0g4j2k_Ggc4&list=PLzuuYNsE1EZAXYR4FJ75jcJseBmo4KQ9-&index=5) about Reinforcement Learning. According to his lectures, policy $\pi$ is evaluated by evaluating another policy $\mu$.

But I cannot understand: why is it so? I would really appreciate if somebody could explain it to me.

Comment: Could you please give a reference to a specific lecture and slides/time? There are lots of types of RL-solving algorithms, and not all of them would use this notation, but there is more than one type that could. This notation might be used about off-policy learning in e.q. Q learning, but it could also be used in deterministic policy gradients, which is a very different algorithm and would need a different explanation

Answer (score 0):

In Monte Carlo and TD, we have to assure that all combinations of actions and states are visited an infinite number of times.

In principle, there are two ways:

- on-policy - you work with one policy only which implicitly combines the exploration and exploitation, e.g. a form of $\epsilon$-greedy
- off-policy - you are trying to find the best (or target) policy, but you explore your environment with another, behavior policy

The distinguishing these two policies is a very powerful tool because of two main reasons:

- You can use historical data that were not optimal, generate e.g. by a human operator.
- You can stay focused on the deterministic target. If you get a randomized policy from an on-policy method, will engineers who shall integrate your controller in a broader system trust you?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly without any context, however, I believe, it's related to what Karel says [in his answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/375523/92007).

$Q$-learning is off-policy since you are greedy when you compute a TD error: you take $\max_{a'}{Q(s',a')}$. 
However, when you do the rollout, you are not greedy all the time, you do exploratory actions (e.g. $\epsilon$-greedy).